# Unhandled Execution Error on JavascriptContext.Run

Tags: javascript, javascript.net

When using Noesis.Javascript:

I am randomly getting this error on a Hello World example-code on a "clean" asp.net project.
The error happens very randomly, with no apparent pattern.
I am using this nuget package:

```
<package id="Noesis.Javascript" version="0.7.1.0" targetFramework="net471" />
```

[image: The code]

With some further testing i have found that this only happens when i use the x64 version of Noesis.Javascript.dll.
When i switch to x86 and set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to True in the App pool, i do not get the error.
This is not a fix for me, as i need to be able to run x64.

Additional details here: https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net/issues/31